# Syntax Error: expected expression, got '<='

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, background-image

Trying to change background image based on two variables in a nested if/then statement.  I get a syntax error for line 17 (syntax error: expected expression, got '<=')

I read some posts on similar topics but they seemed to be unrelated or I just didn't understand what was being said... this is just regular JS and there aren't any .js being referenced.  Should there be?  There's no jquery etc.

In my fantasy the time will be passed to this page and result in a time-appropriate image (from a set of three) to be randomly displayed (e.g., a nighttime visitor would see one of three nighttime images) in the background.  I include this in case someone has a better system than what I have cobbled together below.

```
randomLocale = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
if (randomLocale <= 3 ) {
    if (time >= 730 && <= 1830) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_daytime_01.png)";
    } else if (time >= 2100 && <=530) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_night_01.png)";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_dusk_01.png)";
    }
} else if (randomLocale >= 7) {
    if (time >= 730 && <= 1830) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_daytime_02.png)";
    } else if (time >= 2100 && <=530) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_night_02.png)";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_dusk_02.png)";
    }
} else {
    if (time >= 730 && <= 1830) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_daytime_03.png)";
    } else if (time >= 2100 && <=530) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_night_03.png)";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/cloister_dusk_03.png)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that it expected an expression, but got '<='.

Comment: Even after you fix the syntax error, you're code will not work, because of course a time could never be after 2100 and before 0530 at the same time. You will probably need to change this to something like `time >= 2100 || time <=530`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Well, yes, that is what is says isn't it.  I think "2200" is a time that is after "2100" and before "0530" if you are not concerned about the date, just the rolling 24 hour clock?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now that I have the rest of the page working.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This

```
else if (time >= 2100 && <=530) {
```

is missing a variable between the ampersands and the less than sign.

If you want to check if a variable is between two values, you need to do something like:

```
if (x >= 1 && x <= 15)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed that and there is no error shown, but the code still does not work.  No background image displays at all.  The images are correctly named and in the correct folder so I am at a loss as to why they won't randomly change when the page is loaded based on the time variable.

Comment: Use alerts to trace the code execution. For example: alert('7-13');

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem!

Answer (score -1):

This line:  `if (time >= 730 && <= 1830) {`

is supposed to be  `if (time >= 730 && time <= 1830) {`

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed that and there is no error shown, but the code still does not work.  No background image displays at all.  The images are correctly named and in the correct folder so I am at a loss as to why they won't randomly change when the page is loaded based on the time variable.